# CIFS Windows 10 mount is read only

Tags: permissions, mount, samba, fstab, cifs

I am running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS trying to mount (CIFS/Samba) an NTFS drive on Windows 10 Pro Version 22H2 (OS Build 19045.3693). I actually have it working on one of the Windows drives, but have run out of space. I have another drive that has space and want to use that one. Other than name, size and space available the two drives are identical; both attached via USB to the same hub and have similar security.
No matter what I do, the second mount on Linux ends up read only.
`sudo touch /mnt/mountname/test.txt`
results in `touch: cannot touch '/mnt/mountname/test.txt': Permission denied`

I am using this command to mount:

`sudo mount -t cifs -o credentials=/etc/win_creds/cred_file,dir_mode=0770,file_mode=0770,vers=2.0,uid=1000,gid=0,forceuid,forcegid //192.168.x.x/windrivename/winfolder/anotherwinfolder /mnt/mountname`

I have checked that the Linux permissions on the mount are `rwxrwx---` (both prior to mounting and after mounting).

I have checked to make sure that the user name listed in `cred_file` exists and has Windows permissions to `//192.168.x.x/windrivename/winfolder/anotherwinfolder` (ie Full Control). I have tried both `Workgroup` and `THEACTUALWINDOMAINNAME` as Domain.

I have unmounted and made sure that the `/mnt/mountname` folder has `rwxrwx---` permissions and is owned by the user that is issuing the `mount` command; in addition, the user is a member of `root` and the group owner of `/mnt/mountname` is `root`.

I have tried `vers=1.0` and `vers=3.0`.

There are no error messages with `dmesg | grep CIFS`.

There are no error messages in Windows Event Viewer -> Security nor System.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I didn't realize the Windows Share name was different than the name of the actual Drive in Windows. Ie the Windows Share has nothing to do with Linux CIFS (both of my drives are Windows shared). I think it's a defect that `mount.CIFS` doesn't throw an error when the Windows drive/directory doesn't actually exist,  (because I had it misspelled). Hopefully I can help someone in the future resolve this.

Make sure you have the correct spelling of the Windows Drive name (ignore any Windows sharing).

`windrivename` here in Windows

[image]

must match here in the mount CIFS command:
`//192.168.x.x/windrivename/`